# AWS Glue MySQLSyntaxErrorException while storing data into AWS RDS / Aurora

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-glue

Recently restarted using AWS Glue.

Ran into a sudden `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException` while the code `o125.pyWriteDynamicFrame` was executed.
The error indicated `Access denied for user 'admin'@'%' to database 'mysql' at ...`

> File "/tmp/Dump to S3", line 40, in  datasink4 =
> glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf(frame =
> dropnullfields3, catalog_connection = "gsipre_output",
> connection_options = {"dbtable":
> "myxp_speaker__myxp_livestream_sessions", "database": "mysql"},
> transformation_ctx = "datasink4") File
> "/opt/amazon/lib/python3.6/site-packages/awsglue/dynamicframe.py",
> line 665, in from_jdbc_conf redshift_tmp_dir, transformation_ctx) File
> "/opt/amazon/lib/python3.6/site-packages/awsglue/context.py", line
> 312, in write_dynamic_frame_from_jdbc_conf catalog_id) File
> "/opt/amazon/lib/python3.6/site-packages/awsglue/context.py", line
> 328, in write_from_jdbc_conf return DataSink(j_sink,
> self).write(frame_or_dfc) File
> "/opt/amazon/lib/python3.6/site-packages/awsglue/data_sink.py", line
> 35, in write return self.writeFrame(dynamic_frame_or_dfc, info) File
> "/opt/amazon/lib/python3.6/site-packages/awsglue/data_sink.py", line
> 31, in writeFrame return
> DynamicFrame(self._jsink.pyWriteDynamicFrame(dynamic_frame._jdf,
> callsite(), info), dynamic_frame.glue_ctx, dynamic_frame.name +
> "_errors") File
> "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py",
> line 1257, in **call** answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id,
> self.name) File
> "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line
> 63, in deco return f(*a, **kw) File
> "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py",
> line 328, in get_return_value format(target_id, ".", name), value)
> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling
> o125.pyWriteDynamicFrame. :
> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Access
> denied for user 'admin'@'%' to database 'mysql' at
> sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
> at
> sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) at
> com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404) at
> com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387) at
> com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:942) at
> com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3966) at
> com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3902) at
> com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2526) at
> com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2673) at
> com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2545) at
> com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdateInternal(StatementImpl.java:1540)
> at
> com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeLargeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:2595)
> at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1468)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.glue.GlueJDBCSink$.createTable(GlueJDBCSink.scala:112)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.glue.GlueJDBCSink$.save(GlueJDBCSink.scala:39)
> at
> com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JDBCWrapper.writeDF(JDBCUtils.scala:823)
> at
> com.amazonaws.services.glue.sinks.MySQLDataSinkHelpers$.write(MySqlDataSink.scala:119)
> at
> com.amazonaws.services.glue.sinks.MySqlDataSink.writeDynamicFrame(MySqlDataSink.scala:146)
> at
> com.amazonaws.services.glue.DataSink.pyWriteDynamicFrame(DataSink.scala:58)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at
> py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244) at
> py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357) at
> py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282) at
> py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
> at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79) at
> py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238) at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

```
Here is the AWS Glue auto-generated script 
`datasink4 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf(frame = dropnullfields3, catalog_connection = "gsipre_output", connection_options = {"dbtable": "tbl__name", "database": "mysql"}, transformation_ctx = "datasink4") `

Unsure where I have gone wrong.
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you granted all privileges in mysql.tbl__name to the user/group that you are using in 'gsipre_output'.

To do that, go to your MySQL Workbench and execute:

`GRANT ALL on mysql.tbl__name to group your_user_group;`

There could be other problems too like your IAM role without sufficient permission (check if it has AmazonRedshiftDataFullAccess) or even the ownership of the table, but the one I mentioned first is usually the most common issue.